# Cannot get 180 day sql date to work

Tags: mysql, sql, date, select

```
SELECT CTT.BAN, `Company`, `CID`, `FName`, `MInit`, 
   `LName`, `OName`, `Address`, `City`, `State`, 
   `PostalCode`, `ActiveDate`, `ClosedDate`, `Draft`, 
   `Credit`, `BillingCycle`, `BillingFreq`, `Suspended`, 
   `Paperless` , BTT.Bal 
FROM CustomerT CTT
  JOIN BalanceT BTT
ON (CTT.BAN = BTT.BAN)
WHERE  `Paperless` !=  '1'
   AND `BankDraft` != -1
   AND `CreditCard` != -1
   AND (`BillingCycle` = '1' OR `BillingCycle` = '0')
   AND `Bal` > 2 
   AND (`AccountClosedDate` IS NULL OR 
            DATE(`AccountClosedDate`) >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 180 DAY)  )
```

Everything works with this query but the 180 date peice i have tried several things from this site, with no luck. I need to include into the table only the last 6 months closed acount.

Comment: Shouldn't it be **>=** (NOW() - INTERVAL 180 DAY) - I mean AccountClosedDate greater than, not less than, 180 days ago?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this with [**DATE_ADD**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add)

```
SELECT CTT.BAN, `Company`, `CID`, `FName`, `MInit`, `LName`, `OName`, `Address`, `City`, `State`, `PostalCode`, `ActiveDate`, `ClosedDate`, `Draft`, `Credit`, `BillingCycle`, `BillingFreq`, `Suspended`, `Paperless` , BTT.Bal 
FROM CustomerT CTT
JOIN BalanceT BTT ON
(CTT.BAN = BTT.BAN)
WHERE  `Paperless` !=  '1'
AND `BankDraft` != -1
AND `CreditCard` != -1
AND (`BillingCycle` = '1' OR `BillingCycle` = '0')
AND `Bal` > 2 
AND (`AccountClosedDate` IS NULL OR DATE(`AccountClosedDate`) >=DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -180 DAY))
```

or use `( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 180 DAY )`

```
SELECT CTT.BAN, `Company`, `CID`, `FName`, `MInit`, `LName`, `OName`, `Address`, `City`, `State`, `PostalCode`, `ActiveDate`, `ClosedDate`, `Draft`, `Credit`, `BillingCycle`, `BillingFreq`, `Suspended`, `Paperless` , BTT.Bal 
FROM CustomerT CTT
JOIN BalanceT BTT ON
(CTT.BAN = BTT.BAN)
WHERE  `Paperless` !=  '1'
AND `BankDraft` != -1
AND `CreditCard` != -1
AND (`BillingCycle` = '1' OR `BillingCycle` = '0')
AND `Bal` > 2 
AND (`AccountClosedDate` IS NULL OR DATE(`AccountClosedDate`) >=( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 180 DAY ))
```

Comment: The OP has `<=`, not `>=`. Quite possible that that's the actual error. In that case, his original query should work with just this minor correction.

Comment: @AndreiTanas OP asked for ***I need to include into the table only the last 6 months closed account*** and also see OP's edited question

Comment: @dianuj Your second solution worked like a charm. Thank you, I was so close yet so far away.  ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 180 DAY ) Worked.